# Twitter BootStrap - Responsive Design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have followed the instructions on the Twitter Bootstrap site to post the following two lines of code into my pages head

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Unfortunately the responsive functionality is not working properly.
Are there other things I should be aware of?
Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Perhaps if I post the code of the index page.

See Below

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Welcome to Rentraro.com - Holiday Home Rental Accommodation & Property Management, Rarotonga, Cook Islands, South Pacific</title>
        <meta name="verify-v1" content="gTdq786N6XdrCTtj7ulUYYLtkvVDNwR5INO860wLw8Y=" /> 
        <meta name="keywords" content="Accommodation, Heritage, Muri, Rentraro, holiday home rental, rarotonga accommodation, 
        holiday rental, vacation home rental, vacation house rental, Rent, Rental, Rarotonga, Cook Islands, South Pacific, Beach, 
        lagoon, luxury, Bungalows, Polynesia, South Seas, studio apartment, self contained, private home, private house, studio, 
        vacation, holiday, diving, honeymoon couples, blue lagoon, mountain, tropical, peaceful, cottages, coral beach units, 
        coral beach, units, family home, sunset, house rental, home rental, familiy, family home rentals, family house rentals, 
        families, secluded, sunset, rarotonga holiday homes, rarotonga holiday house, rarotonga home rental, rarotonga home rentals, 
        property management, cook islands holiday homes, rental home accommodation rarotonga, rarotonga house rental, rarotonga villa rental, 
        rarotonga studio rental, rarotonga information" />
        <meta name="description" content="Property Management and Holiday Home Rental Accomodation Specialists, Rarotonga, Cook Islands, South Pacific" />
        <meta name="content-language" content="en" />
        <meta name="copyright" content="Heritage Holdings, Rarotonga, Cook Islands" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <meta name="rating" content="general" />
        <meta name="revist-after" content="30" />
        <meta name="classification" content="Holiday Home Rental, House Rental, Private Accommodation, South Pacific, Cook Islands, Rarotonga" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- all css start -->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- all css end -->
        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- start of nav -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
        <a class="brand" href="index.html" ><span class="navaho">RentRaro<span style="color: #69c8da">.com</span></span></a>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="homesForRent.html">Homes For Rent</a></li>
        <li><a href="mapOfRarotonga.html">Map of Rarotonga</a></li>
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        href="#">
        Read Me
        <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- links -->
        <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQ's</a></li>
        <li><a href="tipSheet.html">Tip Sheet</a></li>
        <li><a href="rarotongaGuide.html">Rarotonga Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="photoGallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- clock starts here -->
        <p>
        <div id="tP" style="color : white; text-align: right; margin-right: 20px;">
        </div>
        </p>
        <!-- clock ends here  -->
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- nav ends here -->
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <!--- container holding and aligning all content -->



        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->


        <!-- big blue unit start -->
        <div class="hero-unit">
        <div class="text-center">
        <h1><span class="head">Welcome to rentraro.com</span></h1>
        <p>Property management and holiday home rental accommodation specialists<br/>
        Rarotonga | Cook Islands | South Pacific </p>
        <p>
        <br/>
        <a href="aboutUs.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
        Learn more
        </a>

        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- big blue unit end -->

        <div class="row-fluid">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/kia_manuia_cottage_10_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5>Kia Manuia Cottage</h5>
                        <p><a href="kiaManuiaCottage.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/tehoras_homestead_15_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Tehoras Homestead </h5>
                        <p><a href="tehorasHomestead.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/papa_mauris_11_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Papa Mauri's Place</h5>
                        <p><a href="papaMaurisPlace.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    </li>
                       <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/raro_beach_bach_07_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Raro Beach Bach</h5>
                        <p><a href="raroBeachBach.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/te_akapuao_07_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Te Akapuaou Villa</h5>
                        <p><a href="teAkapuaoVilla.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">

                    <a href="#myModal" role="button" style="width: 134px" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-tag icon-white"></i> Latest Specials</a>
                    <a href="#myModal2" role="button" style="width: 134px" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-info-sign icon-white"></i> News</a>
                    <a href="docs/events.pdf" role="button" style="width: 134px" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-info-sign icon-white"></i> Calender of Events</a>

                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/muri_central_14_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5>Muri Central</h5>
                        <p><a href="muriCentral.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/Coffee_House_13_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Coffee House </h5>
                        <p><a href="coffeeHouse.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/temara_sunrise_09_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Temara Sunrise</h5>
                        <p><a href="temaraSunrise.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    </li>
                          <li class="span2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="img/kakaia_retreat_14_sm.jpg" class="img-polaroid" alt="">
                      <div class="caption">
                      <p class="text-error"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>New Listing</p>
                        <h5 class="fad">Kakaia Retreat</h5>
                        <p><a href="kakaiaRetreat.html" class="btn btn-primary">More...</a></p> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                       <li class="span4">

                    <!-- Button to trigger modal 1 and 2 above under te Akapuao -->



                    <!-- Modal1 Specials -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="muted">Latest Specials</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><a href="muriLodge.html">Muri Lodge</a> <br/>December thru Jan NZ$2300.00 per week for the whole house.</br>
                    Feb thru March NZ$1800.00 per week for the whole house.</p>
                    <p class="text-warning">More specials to come.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal2 News & Happenings -->
                    <div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel" class="muted">News and Happenings</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul>
                    <li>03/03/2013 New Website Launched.</li>
                    <li>14/11/2011 We were in the press - <a href="http://www.cinews.co.ck/2011/November/Wed16/local.htm#1111140102" target="_new">Air New Zealand Tourism Awards.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="well">
                   <p class="text-success"><i class="icon-globe"></i>Trending content from our site's pages.<p>
                    <!-- AddThis Trending Content BEGIN -->
                    <div id="addthis_trendingcontent"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fd7a2f13ac8bb1a"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    addthis.box("#addthis_trendingcontent", {
                        feed_title : "",
                        feed_type : "trending",
                        feed_period : "day",
                        num_links : 5,
                        height : "auto",
                        width : "auto",
                        domain : "www.rentraro.com"});
                    </script>
                    <!-- AddThis Trending Content END -->

                    </div>

                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>





        <!--- bottom footer -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
        <div class="text-center">
        <br/>
        <small>
        <address>
        PO Box 2165
        Rarotonga, Cook Islands 
        <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (00682) 55519
        <abbr title="Fax">F:</abbr> (00682) 28017
        <abbr title="Email">E:</abbr> <a href="mailto:heritage@oyster.net.ck?Subject=General Enquiry from Rentraro Home Page">heritage@oyster.net.ck </a><br>
        &#169; www.rentraro.com 2013
        </address>  </small>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>


        <!-- scripts -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/goSquared.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fd7a2f13ac8bb1a"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/clock.js">
        // Clock Script Generated By Maxx Blade's Clock v2.0d
        // http://www.maxxblade.co.uk/clock
        </script>
        <!-- scripts end -->
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you please create a test page , it gets easier to help that way .

Answer (score 1):

If you want responsive design you should also be using the `fluid` versions of containers: `container-fluid` and `row-fluid`.

Comment: I have one container which is fluid and multiple rows which are fluid already.

Answer (score 1):

I you are using the latest Boostrap the responsive file is  included in the main project.

the link you are using will only work if you have bootstrap-responsive.css in the folder assets->css-> in your server or local machine.

you can use the links porvided by [bootstrapcdn](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/?v=03042013192251#tab_quickstart) to include a remote file

**css**

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**js**

```
<script src="http//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or you can download Boostrap [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip) and use it  according to  the relative path of file calling the css or js you are using.

Exemple if the bootstrasp.css and bootstrap.js file are in the same directory of yourfile.html, here is the content of yourfile.html :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript · Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 <link href="bootstrapn.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Hello World!</button>

<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AddThis widget is breaking everything. I tried adding the AddThis widget to another theme using bootstrap/responsive design and things stopped working (i.e. sliders, toggles, etc.).

Specifically, any line containing the addthis_widget.js is causing problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fd7a2f13ac8bb1a">
</script>
```

Only solution I could find is to remove all the AddThis widgets from all my pages.